# based on the match count value the below value needs to be captured into a variable

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, jsr223

I have an requirement like based on the match count value the below value needs to be captured into a variable and pass it to next request.

```
<v13:uniqueTaskIdentifier><v13:taskIdentifier>${Task}</v13:taskIdentifier>
```

Lets say i got 3 values in '***${Task_matchNr}***' my output should be like below :

```
<v13:uniqueTaskIdentifier><v13:taskIdentifier>**Task123**</v13:taskIdentifier><v13:uniqueTaskIdentifier><v13:taskIdentifier>**Task1234**</v13:taskIdentifier><v13:uniqueTaskIdentifier><v13:taskIdentifier>**Task1235**</v13:taskIdentifier>
```

I use JSR223 Sampler:

```
def resultCount = ${Task_matchNr} as int
def ABC = "";
for(i=1;i<=resultCount;i++)
{
    def var_name="Task_"+i
    ABC = vars.get(var_name)
    def result = '<v13:uniqueTaskIdentifier><v13:taskIdentifier>(vars.get(ABC))</v13:taskIdentifier>'
    log.info(result);
}
```

but it's capturing

```
<v13:uniqueTaskIdentifier><v13:taskIdentifier>(vars.get(ABC))</v13:taskIdentifier>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the value:

```
def result = '<v13:uniqueTaskIdentifier><v13:taskIdentifier>' + ABC  + '</v13:taskIdentifier>'
```

Comment: it solved my issue now def result = '<v13:uniqueTaskIdentifier><v13:taskIdentifier>' +ABC + '</v13:taskIdentifier>

Answer (score 0):

1. [Don't reference JMeter Functions or Variables in Groovy code](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as `${Task_matchNr}` as the value will be cached and used on subsequent iterations
2. You need to use [string concatenation](https://dzone.com/articles/concatenate-strings-in-groovy) as your current approach will always return the hard-coded value

You need to amend your code as follows:

```
def resultCount = vars.get('Task_matchNr') as int
def ABC = "";
for (i = 1; i <= resultCount; i++) {
    def var_name = "Task_" + i
    ABC = vars.get(var_name)
    def result = '<v13:uniqueTaskIdentifier><v13:taskIdentifier>' + ABC + '< /v13:taskIdentifier>'
    log.info(result);
}
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dmitri, i amend the code as suggested but ABC value is not capturring, null is replacing the value  <v13:uniqueTaskIdentifier><v13:taskIdentifier>null</v13:taskIdentifier>

Comment: Apologies, it was a typo in the script, now it's corrected